# How to convert Properties to PropertySources?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, `PropertiesConfigurationFactory` has method `setProperties(Properties properties)`.
So my code can write as follow:

```
public Map<String, CacheProperties> resolve() {
    Map<String, Object> cacheSettings = resolveCacheSettings();
    Set<String> beanNames = resolveCacheManagerBeanNames(cacheSettings);
    Map<String, CacheProperties> cachePropertiesMap = new HashMap<>(beanNames.size());

    MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
    propertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("cache", cacheSettings));
    beanNames.forEach(beanName -> {
        CacheProperties cacheProperties = new CacheProperties();
        PropertiesConfigurationFactory<CacheProperties> factory = new PropertiesConfigurationFactory<>(cacheProperties);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.putAll(PropertySourceUtils.getSubProperties(propertySources, beanName));
        factory.setProperties(properties);
        factory.setConversionService(environment.getConversionService());
        try {
            factory.bindPropertiesToTarget();
            cachePropertiesMap.put(beanName, cacheProperties);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });

    return cachePropertiesMap;
}
```

But when I upgrade to spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE. `PropertiesConfigurationFactory` changed the method `setProperties(Properties properties)` to `setPropertySources(PropertySources propertySources)`.

So I changed my code like this:

```
public Map<String, CacheProperties> resolve() {
    Map<String, Object> cacheSettings = resolveCacheSettings();
    Set<String> beanNames = resolveCacheManagerBeanNames(cacheSettings);
    Map<String, CacheProperties> cachePropertiesMap = new HashMap<>(beanNames.size());

    MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
    propertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("cache", cacheSettings));
    beanNames.forEach(beanName -> {
        CacheProperties cacheProperties = new CacheProperties();
        PropertiesConfigurationFactory<CacheProperties> factory = new PropertiesConfigurationFactory<>(cacheProperties);
        //Properties properties = new Properties();
        //properties.putAll(PropertySourceUtils.getSubProperties(propertySources, beanName));
        //factory.setProperties(properties);
        factory.setPropertySources(propertySources);
        factory.setConversionService(environment.getConversionService());
        try {
            factory.bindPropertiesToTarget();
            cachePropertiesMap.put(beanName, cacheProperties);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });

    return cachePropertiesMap;
}
```

But this not work...

Anyone can help me? How to convert Properties to PropertySources?

Comment: Have a look https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Comment: @JohnCho Thanks, but this can not resolve my question

Answer (score 0):

Resolved...

I add `factory.setTargetName(beanName);` before `factory.setPropertySources(propertySources);`, and it works well.